# Can you switch branch while pushing code?

Tags: git

I am pushing some code in my rails projects and it has some 150MB of assets. Now this push is taking a lot of time, as it has to.

Now the question is can I switch branches while these assets are getting push. Push is in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problem, since checking out a branch doesn't touch Git's repository files, which are the one that get read when Git pushes.